# grep expression to find a number

Tags: linux, grep, regular-expression

I would like to find a number in the host name. Usually the hostname of the servers is something like below

```
host01.host.name
host02.host.name
```

I want to get the 2 number characters before the first symbol `.` which is `01` or `02` and assign it to a variable. Can someone help me with suitable command.

Answer (score 2):

`grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

```
grep -Po '^[^\d.]*\K\d+(?=\.)' file.txt
```

- `^[^\d.]*` matches portion before the first digits from start, also making sure there is no `.` before the digits, `\K` discards the match
- `\d+` matches one or more digits
- `(?=\.)` is a zero width positive lookahead pattern making sure there is `.` in front

---

As there will be multiple outputs, you better save those in an array:

```
output=( $(grep -Po '^[^\d.]*\K\d+(?=\.)' file.txt) )
```

Now you can iterate over the array elements or use them by usual array accessing manners e.g. to get the value of n-th element use `"${output[n]}"`, to get all values of all keys use `"${output[@]}"`.

---

`sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^[^[:digit:].]*([[:digit:]]+)\..*/\1/' file.txt
```

- Similar to `grep` one, `^[^[:digit:].]*` matches portion before the first digits from start, also making sure there is no `.` before the digits
- `([[:digit:]]+)` matches one or more digits and put them in captured group 1
- `\..*` matches a `.` and then the rest
- In the replacement only the captured group `\1` is used

---

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
host01.host.name
host02.host.name

$ grep -Po '^[^\d.]*\K\d+(?=\.)' file.txt
01
02

$ sed -E 's/^[^[:digit:].]*([[:digit:]]+)\..*/\1/' file.txt
01
02
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo host01.host.name | grep --only-matching '[0-9]*'
01
```

It uses basic regular expression `[0-9]*` for matching and GNU Grep's `--only-matching` (or maybe `-o` for other Grep) to filter output.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "host01.host.name host02.host.name" | sed 's/\..*//;s/[^0-9]*//'
```

or for you;

```
hostname | sed 's/\..*//;s/[^0-9]*//'
```

alternate solution:

```
echo "host01.host.name host02.host.name" | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -1
```

or for you;

```
hostname | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -1
```